# Is 'use soft wraps' option not available in preferences in PyCharm again? (ver 5.02 professional, MAC)

Tags: python, pycharm

It seems that it was possible to set 'use soft wraps' in PyCharm before:
[Word wrapping in PyCharm Python Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181910/word-wrapping-in-pycharm-python-console)
(i.e. File -> Settings -> Editor -> "Virtual Space" group -> Use soft wraps in console)

However, in version 5.02 (the most recent one, professional, MAC edition) it's missing.
Maybe I overlooked it though.

The only place I think maybe helpful is:
Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Python -> Wrapping and Braces
However, options there don't seem to 'mimic' the 'use soft wraps' option. 
I get a little annoyed of clicking through View -> Active Editor -> Use Soft Wraps every time for every file I work on. Also, key combination for this option is missing as well.

Any advice?

P.S.: The version I was talking about (see description above; Mac 5.02) doesn't have "Virtual Space" group (as in File -> Settings -> Editor -> "Virtual Space" group -> Use soft wraps in console). After downloading upgrade (Mac 5.03 version) I found the answer (see below), which is still different from what you show on your link. 
This question is solved/closed anyways...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word wrapping in PyCharm Python Console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181910/word-wrapping-in-pycharm-python-console)

Comment: The version I was talking about (see description above; Mac 5.02) doesn't have "Virtual Space" group (as in File -> Settings -> Editor -> "Virtual Space" group -> Use soft wraps in console). After downloading upgrade (Mac 5.03 version) I found the answer (see below), which is still different from what you show on your link. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is:

Go to Preferences -> General(click on General) -> Soft Wraps (select 'use soft wraps in editor')

It works in PyCharm 5.03 (so, I assume, update does the job, make sure you updated it from 5.02 to 5.03 version)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it there too, but you can now access it by pressing the toggle button:

[image]

Comment: I assume you are talking about 'Event Log' window (View->Event Log). When I use it (click on 'Use Soft Wraps') it works only for the event logs, not for the code in the main window...

Comment: actually I was talking about the "run" window - which gives the results of the program you run. But I now checked the actual console window and there's soft-wraps there automatically for me.

Comment: also notice you can add soft wrapping to the editor (for all projects - you dont' have to repeat this) by going to settings -> editor -> general -> softwraps -> and check the "use soft wraps in editor" option