# Pycharm to toggle soft wrap in code editor

Tags: pycharm

If you know how to toggle `soft wrap` aka. word wrap while editing code in Pycharm, please share.

My [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/#newwindow=1&q=pycharm%20soft%20wrap%20for%20code%20editor&rct=j) and [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340899/is-use-soft-wraps-option-not-available-in-preferences-in-pycharm-again-ver-5) give me no helpful result(s).

Trying to look in Pycharm setting/preference not helps either.

p.s.

I'm using **PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2**

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Right-click the the left side (with line numbering) and choose your soft wrap option:

[image]

Comment: Oh, so hidden on line number ^^ - I actually tried right-clicking o empty spaces :D

Comment: it is really ugly though, the "newline" starts all the way at the left edge

Comment: 6 years later, and this answer is still correct.  TY.

Answer (score 16):

In the PyCharm keymap if you search for `soft` you get these results: [image: img]

I'm sure one of these will be what you are after

Answer (score 15):

If you want to permanently enable soft wrap for certain file extensions, it can be configured in `Settings > Editor> General`. Under the title Soft Wraps, add your required file extension.

[image: Depiction Image]

The settings can also be accessed by right-click on the line-numbers and selecting `Configure Soft Wraps` as explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-editor-general.html). Also shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38585266/3337089).

[image]

PS: I know it is not what is asked in the question, but this was the first google result when I searched for configuring soft wraps. So, I added the answer here in case anybody else comes looking up for the same.

Comment: That's in my opinion the best way to do it.

Answer (score 12):

There's also another way to accomplish this easily.

```
View -> Active Editor -> Soft-Wrap
```

The "View" is in the toolbar of Pycharm (Pycharm, File, Edit, View....)

Answer (score 1):

Hit `double shift` and start typing what you want to do.  `softwrap`

This will automatically selects the first action.

Just hit `enter` and voilà

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on "FILE" Top left in Pycharm editor
2. Goto Settings
3. Click on Editor
4. Click on General
5. Select the soft wrap option
6. You can edit such that *.py, *.extension, etc.
7. Click on Apply

Follow each step properly

[image: 1]