# How to enable soft-wrap for variables in the Debugger window in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

In PyCharm, there is a way to enable soft-wrap in Python Console:

[image: PyCharm Python Console]

I also found the relevant SO questions for this:

1. [Word wrapping in PyCharm Python Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15181910/10358768)
2. [Pycharm - Enable word wrap in debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492778/10358768)

However, I couldn't find any way to enable soft-wrap for the Debugger Window e.g. currently, to view/check the value of `file_path` variable, I have to scroll:

[image: PyCharm Debugger Window]

This is a sample example, so there is only one variable. However, in the actual code, there can be numerous variables, and having a soft-wrap would be much better as well as quite helpful!

So, how can I enable soft-wrap for the variables in the debugger window so that I don't have to scroll horizontally to check the complete value of the variable(s)?